# Intersection of curves

Tags: intersection-theory

Let $f(x,y)=0$ and $g(x,y)=0$ be curves in $\mathbb R^2$. Assume that the origin $(0,0)\in \mathbb R^2$ is a $d$-fold point of $f$ and an $e$-fold point of $g$, respectively. Let $f_d(x,y)$ be the sum of the terms of degree $d$ in $f(x,y)$, $g_e(x,y)$ be the sum of the terms of degree $e$ in $g(x,y)$. If $f_d(x,y)$ and $g_e(x,y)$ have a common factor of positive degree, then the intersection multiplicity $I_O(f,g)>de.$

Answer (score 3):

This is proved in Fulton's "Algebraic Curves", available online 
[here](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf). The precise reference is Section 3.3, property (5) on p. 37.